# Javascript: Use a function to change variables to true/false

Tags: javascript, function, variables, boolean

I'm having trouble using Boolean True/False within my function.

HTML:

```
<a onclick="selectCategory(animal);">Animal</a>
<a onclick="selectCategory(food);">Food</a>
<a onclick="selectCategory(thing);">Thing</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var animal = false;
var food = false;
var thing = false;

function selectCategory(category)
{
     if(category != true)
     {
          category = true;
     }
     else
     {
          category = false;
     }
}
```

I want this function for example to check if variable "animal" is `false`, then it should turn to `true`. If `true`, then turn to `false`.

Whenever I try this, it always turn to `true`, never back to `false`. The variable `category` doesn't seem to affect my variables `animal`, `food` and `thing`. It only changes `category` to `true` like it's a new variable.

Comment: You're only changing the local variable `category`. But you're not returning that value or storing it anywhere. The function has no real effect on anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely have to return in this case as the changes you make are just local to the function scope. But my approach will be a better way to use a small change by using objects:

```js
var myConfig = {
  animal: false,
  food: false,
  thing: false
};

function selectCategory(which) {
  myConfig[which] = !myConfig[which];
  console.log(myConfig);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="selectCategory('animal'); return false;">Animal</a>
<a href="#" onclick="selectCategory('food'); return false;">Food</a>
<a href="#" onclick="selectCategory('thing'); return false;">Thing</a>
```

Few points to remember:

- Using an object will not pollute the global scope.
- You cannot pass variables as parameters, where you want to change the original one. It's pass by value and not reference.
- Use `return false` and give `href` for compatibility.
- Use `myVar = !myVar` to toggle boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning a primitive (or any variable at all) won't do anything, by itself, in 99% of situations. Use an object containing boolean values instead, pass the property name, and reassign the property on the object:

```js
const obj = {
  animal: false,
  food: false,
  thing: false
};
function selectCategory(category){
  obj[category] = !obj[category];
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="selectCategory('animal');">Animal</a>
<a onclick="selectCategory('food');">Food</a>
<a onclick="selectCategory('thing');">Thing</a>
```

Comment: Woah... Similar one.